# How to play all video formats in a Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm writing an Chrome Packaged App that needs to be able to play a lot of local video files. I can use the  tag to play files encoded in h.264 and mp3, but not much else. I'll require playback of at least DivX videos and AC3 audio. Is there any way to do this using the HTML5 platform or otherwise using some kind of plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alternatives, but in my opinion the final solution is not going to be very good.

1 - You can try to use a plug-in, for example:
VLC Plug-in - sorry, I have not enough reputation to post more than 2 links :(
Divx Web Player - sorry, I have not enough reputation to post more than 2 links :(

But then you need to rely on the user installing the plug-in. For VLC, the plug-in is not compatible with the latest versions of Mac OS X.

2 - Encode to H.264 or VP8 from a server with an ffmpeg or using a cloud video provider.

3 - Encode from the client side using JavaScript! There is a port of the ffmpeg on javascript (http://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/). I didn't try this method with large files.

4 - Encode from the client side using a Native Client component (https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/). But seems a daunting task to me.

If you are going to go with the first option, assure that your audience is going to install/configure your player and that their OS are supported.

Answer (score 0):

VLC ported to NaCL would be a great first step.

According to a poster on https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=107178, libVLC has been ported to NaCL, but I am not familiar with VLC internals so I could not say how far this gets you in terms of being able to decode different streams.